# Could I use flash in chrome extensions

Tags: google-chrome-extension

i want to load a flash in a chrome extension popup page, but it doesn't work, could i use flash in chrome extensions. By the way, how could i execute a command binary which compiled into nexe and read it's response.

Comment: Since Chrome itself no longer supports flash in ads, I would say no.

Comment: thanks, and how could i execute a nexe binrary,

Comment: To use the binary: [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging)

Comment: @wOxxOm Native Host != nexe.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend against it, but I have been able to embed flash objects after whitelisting the chrome extension protocol. Go  [here](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html) and add `chrome-extension://`. It isn't a reliable thing though as I have had this setting disappear and still work or stay and not work after various updates. Of course since this needs to be changed manually, it isn't practical for a published extension.